# Blob Input vs Trigger different blob responses & deciphering input response

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

In the following setup:

```
import { unzip } from "zlib";
import { promisify } from "util";
const do_unzip = promisify(unzip);

app.storageBlob('callLogReader', {
    path: `/things/{name}`,
    connection: 'qvdsftpblob_STORAGE',
    handler: callLogReader,
});

export async function callLogReader(blob: Buffer, context: InvocationContext): Promise<void> {
    const buf = await do_unzip(blob)
}
```

Do Unzip correctly unzips the buffer file. However once I do:

```
import { unzip } from "zlib";
import { promisify } from "util";
const do_unzip = promisify(unzip);

const blobInput = input.storageBlob({
    connection: 'qvdsftpblob_STORAGE',
    path: '{data.url}'
});

app.eventGrid('callLogEvents', {
    handler: callLogEvents,
    extraInputs: [blobInput],
});

export async function callLogEvents(event: EventGridEvent, context: InvocationContext): Promise<void> {
    context.log('Event grid function processed event:', event);
    const blobFile = context.extraInputs.get(blobInput) as Buffer;
    const buf = await do_unzip(blobFile);
}
```

If fails for invalid header (which means its not in the format i thought). I checked the typescript definition and its unknown and i've having trouble trying to figure out what the input format is so I can correctly unzip it. I've tried googling and digging through documentation to figure out what the format is for the blob in the input and am currently stuck.

Any help would be hugely appreciated